# how to install phone gap and run any website app for iphone

Tags: html, cordova

I want to install phone gap and want to test a website. I installed phonegap but it shows a "cordova framework" installed when creating new project instead of phone gap. How to test html index file?

Comment: cordova is the name for phonegap 1.5

Comment: ok so i have index.html file i have added it in the project it gives errors NSAutoreleas error it shows 9 errors for that i am just testing it in xcode

Comment: have you followed "get started"? http://phonegap.com/start#ios-x4

Comment: yes i have followed but when i creat project there is no any folder www created in that project i am using xcode 4

Comment: in xcode 3.2.6 it shows www folder but gives 2 errors

Answer (score 1):

Create new project -> Cordova-based application.
After that choose the project file and "show in finder", in the same folder should be folder named www (it isn´t there), so create www folder in that location and put your index.html there.
Drag created www folder to xcode. The www folder must appear as blue in xcode, not yellow. To make that happen make sure "Create folder references to any added folders" is selected.